# SUBSTITUTE or REPLACE all non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, substitution, excel-2019

This array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) trim any non-alphanumeric characters:

```
{=TEXTJOIN("";1;MID(D2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2)))*IFERROR(SEARCH(MID(D2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2)));1);"-./ 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")>0;LEN(D2)+1);1))}
```

But I want to substitute/replace this non-alphanumeric characters with simple space, only with regular or array formula.
Its possible?

Comment: Do you have sample data (multiple cases) with expected results? What about the non alpha-numeric characters you got in your current formula?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `=TEXTJOIN("";1;IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(D2;SEQUENCE(LEN(D2));1);"-./ 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));MID(D2;SEQUENCE(LEN(D2));1);" "))`?

Comment: @Rory SEQUENCE is very cool function, but only for 365 office version, But i mean to substitute only non-alphanumeric characters, not entire cell.

Comment: @JvdV I expect this string "OSDNR$234@^55!" trim to "OSDNR 234  55 "

Comment: @JvdV in current formula we have 4 exceptions "-./ "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you can use the following:

[image]

The CSE-entered formula in `B1`:

```
=TRIM(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),"-./ 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")),MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)," ")))
```

For ms365 users:

```
=LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),TRIM(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(X,"-./ 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")),X," "))))
```

It will also prevent your formula from being volatile.

Comment: Its so magical! Thank you, mister magician! And TRIM at the end its perfect.